# Merging two git repositories (accidentally downloaded .zip from github, need to merge back in)

Tags: ios, git, version-control, xcode4, github

Ok so I have an iOS project I'm tracking with git / github.

I downloaded a copy of the master branch (.zip format), and then accidentally started working on that xcode project. So I have

-- Original xCode project where I usually push/pull from github

-- downloaded xcode project that is one step ahead of my project on github.

Basically I want the downloaded/modified project to be my next commit in my original git repository.... but its a completely separate project now. Is there a way I can merge two separate git repositories / projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply copy the files over, then

```
git add -A
git commit
git push
```

Comment: There are quite a few files, and a few I forget if I changed or not. Can I just copy over the entire xcode project and then add commit push?

Comment: Don't worry about over-writing files that did not change. To be sure wipe the git repo working folder first (careful to not erase the .git folder) and then copy the other project. Git status will sure you what changed.